# IOS in app rejection issue - Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

my app have uploaded new version without any new in - app purchase and add just a few new contents
But I've got following message from Apple

---

We are unable to complete the review of your app because one or more of your in-app purchase products have not been submitted for review.

Next Steps

To resolve this issue, please be sure to take action and submit your in-app purchases and upload a new binary in App Store Connect. Learn more about how to offer in-app purchases in App Store Connect Developer Help.

Once you've submitted your in-app purchases and uploaded a new binary, we can proceed with your review.

### Please see attached screenshots for details.

I've tested all the in-app purchase twice more and had nothing to be trouble.

So I submitted the rejected version again and rejected againt because of same reason.

My questions
1. Should I create new binary without any fixes
2. Or is there anybody had trouble like me? and how did you solve it?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to submit your binary and write in the note section (where you can specify any notes for testing,it's the bottom of the page ) that you have rectify issue at your side and if apple finds issue than you needed a detail log for the issue.and they will provide you what's the issue and also mention that a screenshot would be appreciate.